# Login con 3 tipos de usuarios en diferentes colecciones NodeJS, Express, Mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda.

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con NodeJS, Express, MongoDB; como ODM estoy utilizando MONGOOSE.

Tengo tres colecciones: **ESTUDIANTE**, **PARENT**, **PROFESOR**, las tres colecciones o entidades sólo son similares en algunos campos, en su estructura general son muy diferentes.

===============================================================

```
const estudianteSchema = new Schema({
       firstName: String,
       lastName: String,
       name: String,
       email: String,
       password: String,
       .
       .
       .
       // OTROS CAMPOS PROPIOS DE ESTA COLECCIÓN "Estudiante"
});


const profesorSchema = new Schema({
       firstName: String,
       lastName: String,
       name: String,
       email: String,
       password: String,
       .
       .
       .
       // OTROS CAMPOS PROPIOS DE LA COLECCIÓN "Profesor"
});

const parentSchema = new Schema({
       firstName: String,
       lastName: String,
       name: String,
       email: String,
       password: String,
       .
       .
       .
       // OTROS CAMPOS PROPIOS DE LA COLECCIÓN "Parent", parent es el padre del estudiante.
});
```

================================================================

Al haber tres colecciones diferentes se presentan varios inconvenientes al momento de desarrollar el login:

1. Al momento de insertar *Estudiante*, *Profesor* o *Parent*, No hay forma de controlar el campo ***único*** como gmail, esto daría lugar a que existan un profesor y un estudiante con el mismo ***email***.
2. Para hacer el login tendría que realizar tres rutas diferentes:

   http://localhost:3000/estudiante/login

   http://localhost:3000/profesor/login

   http://localhost:3000/parent/login

Una sola ruta sería lo ideal, pero para hacer una sola ruta cada vez que alguien haga un login el sistema tendría que recorrer las tres colecciones para encontrar al usuario, lo cual no creo que sea lo mas conveniente por el poreformance...

En las bases de datos Relaciones esto se solucionaría con una normalización.

Entonces: ¿Cuál sería la mejor solución para esto en mongoDB y mongoose?.

Gracias, agradecido de antemano a cualquier héroe sin capa.

Comment: ¿Buen día, Encontraste la solución?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás enfocando tu estructura de datos de manera muy normalizada, de hecho casi de forma relacional.

MongoDB te permite más libertad a la hora de trabajar con los datos y además te permitirá usar un enfoque de POO mucho más flexible del que se provee en una Base de Datos relacional.

**¿Datos normalizados o embebidos?**

La primera decisión que tomamos es sobre el diseño de los datos que usaré en mi sistema. Los datos normalizados, tal como los tienes actualmente, intentan separar las diferentes entidades y sus correspondientes dependencias para evitar la duplicidad de información y el exceso de campos inútiles en un documento. En las bases de datos relacionales esta parte puede llegar a ser muy importante ya que las tablas son estructuras muy rígidas que se adaptan a un esquema fijo. En MongoDB, la estructura de los documentos es *schemaless* (sin esquema), por lo tanto no tenemos la rigidez de una tabla, por el contrario puedo almacenar en una misma colección documentos que no tienen nada que ver unos con otros.

Pero como somos seres que buscamos el orden en el caos, siempre vamos a intentar que nuestros documentos mantengan cierta coherencia y además esto nos permitirá cierta eficiencia al momento de analizar y realizar búsqueda de datos, ya que un esquema en particular nos permitirá crear los índices apropiados. Es allí en donde entra en juego un Modelador de Objetos de Datos (ODM) como [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/), que nos va a permitir crear una esquema para nuestros datos.

Los datos embebidos nos ayudan en una situación muy particular: las transacciones. Y es que hasta MongoDB 4.0 no existía forma de realizar transacciones multi-documento de manera nativa, y se tenía que recurrir a sistemas de lógica de aplicación con transacciones en 2 fases. Los datos embebidos no sufren de este problema, ya que toda operación de escritura sobre un único documento es atómica.

Volviendo al tema que nos trajo hasta aquí, una forma de resolver el problema que tienes actualmente (digo *una forma*, porque existe más de una), sería pensar en roles.

Si bien tus entidades son 3 bien diferenciadas: `estudiante`, `profesor`, `parent`, todos comparten una raíz común (o al menos eso es lo ideal), todos son usuarios de tu sistema.

Así, un usuario puede ser: `estudiante` o puede ser `parent` o puede ser `profesor`. Incluso, nuestra solución nos va a permitir plantear el caso en que exista mezcla entre ellos (un estudiante puede ser preparador en una materia, un profesor puede ser padre de un estudiante, un padre puede estudiar la misma carrera junto con su hijo, un profesor de pregrado puede tomar clases de postgrado, etc.), pero eso va más allá del alcance de la pregunta formulada.

**Usando datos embebidos**

Si pensamos en datos embebidos, una forma de lograr lo que te propones es la siguiente:

```js
// Esquema de estudiante
const EstudianteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  matricula: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Matricula'
  },
  cursos: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Curso'
    }
  ]
});

// Esquema de profesor
const ProfesorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  afiliacion: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    index: true
  },
  cursos: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Curso'
    }
  ],
  nomina: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Nomina'
  }
});

// Esquema de padre
const ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  hijos: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Usuario'
    }
  ],
  pago: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Pago'
  }
});

// Esquema de Usuario
const UsuarioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  estudiante: {
    type: EstudianteSchema
  },
  profesor: {
    type: ProfesorSchema
  },
  parent: {
    type: ParentSchema
  }
}, {collection: 'users', timestamps: {createdAt: 'created', updatedAt: 'updated'}});

const Usuario = mongoose.model('Usuario', UsuarioSchema);
```

Ahora es muy sencillo crear una instancia de usuario tipo `Estudiante`, `Parent` y/o `Profesor`. Para esto, lo importante es modelar tu vista para representar correctamente los datos que deseas ingresar a tu sistema.

```js
//ruta que maneja la creación de un usuario
router.route('users')
.post((req, res, next) => {
  let user = new Usuario(req.body); // <- el cuerpo de la solicitud contiene los datos exactamente como los tengo implementados en mi esquema de usuario
  Usuario.save()
  .then(saved => {
    console.log(saved);
    //..
  })
  .catch(errorHandler);
});
```

Para consultar los datos podemos hacer uso de [`Query string`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), al fin y al cabo es la manera idónea de filtrar resultados. Esta parte de la lógica es a tu entera discreción, puedes manejar los filtros de la forma que más se adapte a tus necesidades, yo sólo pondré un ejemplo.

Supongamos que deseo la lista de estudiantes, puedo manejar la siguiente ruta, usando una `query string`:

```
GET /users?type=estudiante
```

```js
router.route('/users')
.get((req, res, next) => {
  let filter = {};
  if(req.query && req.query.type) {
    filter[req.query.type] = {$exists: true}
  }
  User.find(filter)
  .then(results => {
    console.log(results);
    //...
  })
  .catch(errorHandler);
});
```

Cuando se crea un documento de tipo usuario, el mismo va a tener al menos uno de los tres campos (`estudiante`, `parent`, `profesor`). La consulta anterior me devuelve sólo los documentos que contengan el campo `estudiante`. Para esto me he apoyado en el operador de consulta de MongoDB [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists)

Esta consulta es muy rígida, ¿qué pasa si deseo la lista de profesores que a la vez son estudiantes? Pues debo pensar en otra forma de realizar la consulta. Por ejemplo:

```
GET /users?estudiante=true&profesor=true
```

Luego mi controlador puede procesarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
router.route('/users')
.get((req, res, next) => {
  let filter = {};
  if(req.query) {
    let arr = Object.keys(req.query).map(key => {
      let obj = {}
      obj[key] = { $exists: req.query[key].toLowerCase() === 'true' ? true : false }
      return obj;
    });
    // sólo agrego el filtro si hay algo que agregar
    if(arr.length) {
      filter.$and = arr;
    }
  }
  User.find(filter)
  .then(results => {
    console.log(results);
    //...
  })
  .catch(errorHandler);
});
```

Esto es más o menos una aproximación a la solución al problema planteado. En este caso no sólo es un cambio en el uso de las rutas, sino un cambio en la estructura de los datos.

En este último ejemplo, estoy usando un código bastante particular para construir el filtro usado en la consulta a la base de datos, básicamente estoy leyendo las claves del objeto `req.query`, luego, basado en el valor de cada clave, genero un objeto para cada una de ellas que será incorporado a un `array` de objetos, esto con la finalidad de usar el operador [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and) de MongoDB, que recibe como parámetro una lista con objetos de condiciones que se deben cumplir.

Las condiciones serán establecidas usando el operador que ya hemos visto: `$exists`.

Un ejemplo de dicho código funcionando sería:

```js
// ejemplo de objeto req.query
// se obtiene de una solicitud GET /users?estudiante=true&parent=true
let req = {
  query: {
    estudiante: 'true',
    parent: 'true'
  }
}
let filter = {};
if(req.query) {
  let arr = Object.keys(req.query).map(key => {
    let obj = {}
    obj[key] = { $exists: req.query[key].toLowerCase() === 'true' ? true : false }
    return obj;
  });
  // sólo agrego el filtro si hay algo que agregar
  if(arr.length) {
    filter.$and = arr;
  }
}

console.log(filter);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Edición**

En el código anterior había un error al crear el objeto de filtro, sólo se añade el `Array` generado si el mismo contiene información, de lo contrario usar un `Array` vacío provoca que la consulta no devuelva ningún resultado.

**Datos Normalizados**

Hasta ahora hemos logrado usar una misma colección para todos los documentos de usuario, independientemente del tipo que representen. Sin embargo podemos vernos en la necesidad de normalizar los datos por razones de escalabilidad o por razones de lógica de aplicación.

Lo cierto es que podemos conservar la misma estructura de datos que tenemos hasta ahora, pero vamos a crear una colección para `estudiantes` otra colección para `profesores` y otra colección para `parents`.

El cambio será en la forma en que relacionamos los datos de usuario con los datos de las entidades diferenciadas. Ya no vamos a incrustarlos dentro de nuestro documento, sino que por el contrario vamos a crear una referencia.

Los esquemas para estos modelos se ven igual que antes, pero ahora, vamos a indicar que cada una se almacenará en una colección de la DB y vamos a crear el modelo de datos para cada esquema.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// Esquema de estudiante
const EstudianteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  //... datos del esquema
}, {collection: 'estudiantes', timestamps: {createdAt: 'created', updatedAt: 'updated'}}); // <- indico que usará la colección 'estudiantes'
// creo el modelo de datos
const Estudiante = mongoose.model('Estudiante', EstudianteSchema);

// Esquema de profesor
const ProfesorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  //.. datos el esquema
}, {collection: 'profesores', timestamps: {createdAt: 'created', updatedAt: 'updated'}}); // <- indico que usará la colección 'profesores'
// creo el modelo de datos
const Profesor = mongoose.model('Profesor', ProfesorSchema);

// Esquema de padre
const ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // ... datos del esquema
}, {collection: 'parents', timestamps: {createdAt: 'created', updatedAt: 'updated'}}); // <- indico que usará la colección 'parents'
// creo el modelo de datos
const Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', ParentSchema);

//ahora puedo crear las referencias en el modelo de Usuario
const UsuarioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // .. datos del esquema
  estudiante: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Estudiante'
  },
  profesor: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Profesor'
  },
  parent: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Parent'
  }
}, {collection: 'users', timestamps: {createdAt: 'created', updatedAt: 'updated'}});

const Usuario = mongoose.model('Usuario', UsuarioSchema);
```

Con esto hemos creado referencias en el modelo `Usuario` que apuntan a documentos en las otras colecciones. Ahora necesitamos obtener la información de dichos documentos cuando hacemos una consulta a la colección de usuarios.

Nos podemos apoyar en el método [`populate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) del objeto [`Model`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model) de Mongoose.

Por ejemplo, teniendo la misma ruta que creamos anteriormente, podemos añadir una condición luego de obtener la lista filtrada de documentos.

Para ello necesitamos construir una lista de objetos que contendrán las rutas o propiedades a ser llenadas con información de las diferentes colecciones.

Lo podemos hacer así:

```js
router.route('/users')
.get((req, res, next) => {
  let filter = {};
  if(req.query) {
    let arr = Object.keys(req.query).map(key => {
      let obj = {}
      obj[key] = { $exists: req.query[key].toLowerCase() === 'true' ? true : false }
      return obj;
    });
    // sólo agrego el filtro si hay algo que agregar
    if(arr.length) {
      filter.$and = arr;
    }
  }
  User.find(filter)
  .then(users => {
    // ahora que tengo los resultados lleno los campos que necesito con populate
    let options = [];  // lista que pasaremos al método populate
    if(req.query) {
      options = Object.keys(req.query).filter(key => {
        return req.query[key].toLocaleLowerCase() === 'true' ? true : false;
      }).map(path => {return { path };})
    }
    // usaremos el método populate sólo si se han solicitado estos datos
    if(options.length) {
      return Usuario.populate(users, options, (error, result) => {
        if(error) {
          return res.status(500).json({message: 'Error', error: error.message});
        }
        return res.status(200).json({message: 'OK', users: result});
      });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({message: 'OK', users});
    //...
  })
  .catch(errorHandler);
});
```

Nuevamente explico un poco el código para la obtención de la lista de opciones. Sabemos que la ruta puede contener los siguiente parámetros:

```
GET /users?estudiante=true&parent=true
```

Entonces, necesitamos filtrar (como ya lo hacemos) y luego traer la información relativa a esos campos (`estudiante` y `parent`) que se encuentra almacenada en otra colección. Por lo tanto la lista de opciones que vamos a pasar al método `populate` debe ser de la siguiente forma:

```js
[
  {path: 'estudiante'},
  {path: 'parent'}
]
```

Para lograrlo me apoyo en los métodos de los `Array` de Javascript: [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) y [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map). El primero para filtrar que los campos sean aquellos que ponen `true` y la segunda para construir el objeto.

Un ejemplo:

```js
let req = {
  query: {
    estudiante: 'true',
    parent: 'true'
  }
}
let options = [];
if(req.query) {
  options = Object.keys(req.query).filter(key => {
    return req.query[key].toLocaleLowerCase() === 'true' ? true : false;
  }).map(path => {return { path };})
}
console.log(options);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Esta sería una primera implementación usando datos normalizados, la forma en que se construye la consulta es decisión de quien esté diseñando la aplicación.

Uno de los desafíos con esta forma de trabajar es a la hora de realizar operaciones de actualización de datos. Por ejemplo, al momento de crear un usuario, hay que garantizar que tanto el documento de la entidad (o entidades) a la que pertenece el mismo y el documento de usuario que enlaza con esta entidad sean creados. Si algo falla, necesitamos una forma de rechazar los cambios y dejar la información consistente.

Es por ello que a partir de MongoDB 4.0 se introduce la posibilidad de transacciones multi-documento. Sin embargo esto sólo está disponible en versiones de conjunto de réplica ([*replica set*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/)) o a partir de MongoDB 4.2 también en servidores fragmentados ([*sharded cluster*](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/sharding/index.html#sharded-cluster)). Pero para bases de datos independientes no es posible usar transacciones, por lo cual hay que recurrir a lógica de transacciones en 2 fases como solución de la aplicación.

Espero que esto te aclare las dudas y te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio por este gran y valioso aporte..., me pongo a trabajar en este enfoque y te aviso los resultados.

Comment: Mañana añadiré cómo hacerlo con datos normalizados, que es el enfoque de tu pregunta, el cambio es sutil pero poderoso. Saludos @jayo

Comment: Te lo agradeceré muchísimo Mauricio.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Mauricio muy agradecido... empezaré a trabajar en ello, te aviso los resultados. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Poniendo en práctica la primera solución ***Documentos Embebidos*** que plantea @Mauricio_Contreras (que por cierto le estoy muy agradecido), casi todo salió bien hasta este momento, sin embargo surgió un problema al momento de insertar o guardar los documentos, resulta que sólo guarda un documento de cada tipo: ***Estudiante***, ***Profesor***, ***Parent***.

Por ejemplo al guardar el segundo documento de tipo ***Estudiante*** muestra el ***Error***:

E11000 duplicate key error collection: qmuneddb.usuarios index: profesor.rda_1 dup key: { profesor.rda: null }

El problema muestra que, cuando se guarda un documento de tipo ***Estudiante***, ya existe un documento con el campo ***rda: null*** en el subdocumento embebido de tipo ***Profesor*** que nada tiene que ver con los campos del ***Estudiante***.

```
// Esquema de Usuario
const UsuarioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  estudiante: {
    type: EstudianteSchema
  },
  profesor: {
    type: ProfesorSchema
  },
  parent: {
    type: ParentSchema
  }
}, {collection: 'users', timestamps: {createdAt: 'created', updatedAt: 'updated'}});

const Usuario = mongoose.model('Usuario', UsuarioSchema);
```

Entonces se podría pensar que, por la estructura que tiene el esquema ***usuario***, Mongoose, NO solamente guarda una instancia, es decir cuando insertamos un usuario de tipo ***Estudiante***, también inserta los otros subdocumentos embebidos ***Profesor*** y ***Parent***, aunque no se lo indiquemos específicamente.

Lo ideal sería que cuando guardes un ***usuario*** de tipo ***estudiante***, no guarde nada referido al ***Profesor*** o ***Parent***.

***¿Cuál sería la solución apropiada para esto?***

Gracias de antemano.