# Referencia de un campo a dos modelos. Mongodb

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

les explico un poco. Imaginense que tengo una pagina web donde hay un apartado de mensajeria, tengo dos tipos de usuario (profesor y alumno). Al crear el modelo de mensaje me encuentro con el siguiente problema.

```
var MensajeSchema= Schema({
    texto: String,
    visto: String,
    asunto: String,
    emisor: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Alumno'},
   
    receptor: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Alumno'},
    
    fecha: {type:Date, default: Date.now},
}) ;
```

En el apartado de emisor y receptor pueden enviar/recibir mensajes ambos usuarios (Profesor y Alumno) ¿Cómo puedo referenciarlos en el modelo?

He utilizado el siguiente modelo:

```
var MensajeSchema= Schema({
    texto: String,
    visto: String,
    asunto: String,
    emisor: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Alumno'},
    emisor: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Profesor'},
    receptor: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Alumno'},
    receptor: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Profesor'},
    fecha: {type:Date, default: Date.now},
}) ;
```

Pero me encuentro con el problema que si el emisor es de tipo profesor y el receptor de tipo Alumno, no me encuentra el Alumno ya que el emisor ha sido profesor por lo que busca en esa base de datos.

Espero que me podais ayudar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 4):

Tu problema es sobre el diseño del modelo de datos, y atacando eso obtendrás una solución que sea adecuada a tus necesidades.

**El Modelo**

Entiendo que deseas crear una colección de `mensajes` donde puedas almacenar cada mensaje enviado/recibido desde un usuario hacia otro usuario. El problema es que tienes diferentes colecciones para tipos de usuario: colección de profesores, y colección de alumnos.

En MongoDB puedes trabajar con documentos tan complejos como tu imaginación o necesidad lo permitan.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Supongamos que no vamos a alterar las colecciones de profesor y alumno, por ahora, y vamos a concentrarnos en solucionar el problema actual.

Podríamos crear el esquema de datos y usar la información del usuario que envía el mensaje y la información de quien lo recibe, de tal forma que al momento de realizar búsquedas podamos usar dicha información para traer la data que necesitamos.

¿Cómo lo hacemos?

La siguiente propuesta de esquema busca cubrir esta situación:

```js
const MensajeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  texto: String,
  visto: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  asunto: String,
  emisor: {
    estudiante: {
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Alumno'
    },
    profesor: {
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Profesor'
    }
  },
  receptor: {
    estudiante: {
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Alumno'
    },
    profesor: {
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Profesor'
    }
  },
  fecha: {type:Date, default: Date.now},
});
```

Al momento de crear un mensaje, simplemente debemos establecer los valores adecuados en nuestro objeto a modelar.

Por ejemplo, el estudiante @Pikoh identificado con el `id`: "5f4ce815110defdbf5fedf05" en la colección de estudiantes, desea enviarle un mensaje a su profesor @gbianchi identificado con el `id`: "5f4ce81c110defdbf5fedf06" en la colección de profesores. Entonces el objeto que usaremos para crear el mensaje simplemente será:

```js
let mensaje = new Mensaje({
  texto: "Deseo más información sobre el curso de Java, ya que me encanta ese lenguaje.",
  asunto: "Sobre Curso de JAVA",
  emisor: {
    estudiante: "5f4ce815110defdbf5fedf05"
  },
  receptor: {
    profesor: "5f4ce81c110defdbf5fedf06"
  }
});
```

Evidentemente si @Pikoh es un estudiante, debe estar registrado como tal en el sistema y si deseo enviarle un mensaje a un profesor o a otro alumno, lo escogeré de una lista de profesores o de alumnos.

Sin saber cómo tienes organizada la vista de tus datos o cómo es la lógica del `frontend` para el envío de mensajes, poco más te puedo decir.

Notemos que sólo se llena un campo tanto para emisor como para receptor, sea este para estudiante o para profesor, pero nunca incluiré 2 campos en emisor o 2 campos en receptor, aunque mi modelo de datos indica que puede recibir ambos. MongoDB no creará campos que no aparezcan en nuestro modelo de datos, simplemente los omitirá. Esto nos garantiza que cada documento almacenado tendrá un solo valor para los campo emisor y receptor.

Ahora, si usamos este esquema de datos, necesitamos una forma de consultar los mensajes.

Para saber cuántos y cuáles mensajes ha enviado el alumno @Pikoh, por ejemplo sería la siguiente:

```
Mensaje.find({ "emisor.estudiante": "5f4ce815110defdbf5fedf05"}, callback);
```

Esto nos va a devolver la lista de todos los mensajes emitidos por el estudiante @Pikoh.

Lo mismo si queremos ver todos los mensajes recibidos por el profesor @gbianchi, pordemos hacer la siguiente consulta:

```js
Mensaje.find({"receptor.profesor": "5f4ce81c110defdbf5fedf06"}, callback);
```

Y si quiero ver cuantos mensajes le ha enviado el entusiasta alumno @Pikoh al prominente profesor @gbianchi, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```js
Mensaje.find(
  { 
    $and: [
      { "emisor.estudiante": "5f4ce815110defdbf5fedf05" },
      { "receptor.profesor": "5f4ce81c110defdbf5fedf06" }
    ]
  },
  callback);
```

En esta consulta he utilizado el operador [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/index.html) que me permite filtrar la colección buscando datos cuyos campos `emisor.estudiante` y `receptor.profesor` se correspondan ambos con los valores establecidos.

Aún más si deseo la lista de todos los mensajes emitidos por cualquier profesor, puedo hacer lo siguiente:

```js
Mensaje.find(
  {
    "emisor.profesor" : {
      $exists: true
    }
  },
  callback);
```

En esta consulta utilizo el operador [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/index.html), que me filtrará los documentos que contengan un campo `emisor.profesor`.

Si bien esto puede funcionar, particularmente me deja un sinsabor. Y es que yo hubiese escogido otro modelo de datos. Ya que la lógica para manejar los datos actuales se vuelve densa y poco amigable a medida que necesitamos añadir características a nuestro sistema.

**Mejora**

Mi planteamiento de mejora simplemente se basa en un hecho muy particular: tanto `Estudiante` como `Profesor` comparten aspectos similares en cuanto a datos:

- Nombres
- Apellidos
- Correo electrónico
- Nombre de usuario
- Materias (que dicta o que cursa)

Por lo tanto, podemos pensar en crear una sola colección llamada `Usuarios` que contenga todos estos aspectos que tienen en común `Profesor` y `Estudiante` y los aspectos no comunes los podemos incrustar en un subdocumento, por ejemplo:

Subdocumento para estudiante:

- Número matrícula de estudiante
- Notas
- ...

Subdocumento para profesor:

- Número de carnet de profesor
- Clave del baño de profesores
- ...

Un esquema que aplique este concepto:

```js
const UsuarioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nombres: String,
  apellidos: String,
  correo: String,
  nombreUsuario: String,
  materias: [
    {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Materias'}
  ],
  profesor: {
    carnet: String,
    claveDelServicio: String
  },
  alumno: {
    matricula: String,
    notas: [
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Notas'
    ]
  }
});
```

Con una estructura de este tipo, sólo debo llenar el subdocumento adecuado según estemos registrando un alumno o un profesor.

Luego si deseo la lista de todos los usuarios que son profesores solo hacemos la consulta adecuada, por ejemplo:

```js
Usuario.find(
  {
    "profesor": {
      $exists: true
    }
  },
  callback);
```

Una consulta similar es usada para obtener la lista de alumnos.

Ahora, cuando trabajo con los mensajes sólo debo crear la referencia a la colección de usuarios, por ejemplo:

```js
const MensajeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  texto: String,
  visto: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  asunto: String,
  emisor: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Usuario'
  },
  receptor: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Usuario'
  },
  fecha: {
    type:Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

Con este pequeño cambio en el modelo de datos, no hace falta enredarnos en diferenciar el tipo de usuario que envía o recibe el mensaje, ya que todos pertenecen a la misma colección, y al usar el método [`populate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com), traeremos la información del usuario y sabremos si el mismo es profesor o estudiante. Claro, que tenemos que tener cuidado con la forma en que mostramos dicha información, ya que si la consulta la hace un estudiante, puede tener acceso a la información de un profesor, ¡y la clave del baño de profesores es de máxima seguridad!.

En esta respuesta de otra pregunta: [Login con 3 tipos de usuarios en diferentes colecciones NodeJS, Express, Mongoose](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/384855/login-con-3-tipos-de-usuarios-en-diferentes-colecciones-nodejs-express-mongoos/385032#385032), doy más detalles sobre los aspectos a tomar en cuenta a la hora de escoger el modelo de datos y la forma en que podemos realizar ciertas consultas.

## EDICIÓN

Ya que tu [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386174/referencia-de-un-campo-a-dos-modelos-mongodb/386181?noredirect=1#comment691926_386181) está relacionado con esta misma pregunta, edito esta respuesta para reponderte.

**Hacer uso de `populate` usando un esquema con referencia a colecciones separadas**

Te presento 3 opciones para realizar la consulta:

1. **Usar el método `populate` durante la consulta**

En este caso es sencillo, el método [`populate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) devolverá el documento referenciado en el campo sobre el cual se encuentre la referencia.

Por lo tanto, si deseo los datos de estudiante o profesor simplemente puedo usar el método `populate` en cadena. Supongamos que deseo la lista de todos los mensajes, sin importar el filtro de búsqueda. Puedo hacer algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```js
Mensaje.find(filter)
.populate({path: 'emisor.profesor'})
.populate({path: 'emisor.estudiante'})
.populate({path: 'receptor.profesor'})
.populate({path: 'receptor.estudiante'})
.exec(callback); // <- usamos exec() para realizar la consulta y pasamos como argumento nuestra función callback
```

De esta forma le estamos indicando a Mongoose individualmente que deseo poblar los datos de emisor y receptor, tanto para estudiante como para profesor.

Podemos resumir el código anterior de la siguiente forma:

```js
Mensaje.find(filter)
.populate([{path: 'emisor.profesor'}, {path: 'emisor.estudiante'}])
.populate([{path: 'receptor.profesor'}, {path: 'receptor.estudiante'}])
.exec(callback);
```

¡Pero los mensajes sólo tienen un campo profesor o un campo estudiante en cada campo de emisor y receptor!

No pasa nada, [si el campo a llenar no existe o el documento referenciado no existe](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#doc-not-found), el valor devuelto es `null`.

2. **Usar el método `populate` selectivamente**

Si deseo ser selectivo, necesito saber con antelación el tipo de documento que estoy consultando, y esto es determinado por la consulta.

Supongamos que deseo todos los mensajes emitidos por cualquier profesor a cualquier estudiante. Esto es todos los mensajes que contengan un campo `emisor.profesor` y un campo `receptor.estudiante`.

La consulta puede ser parecida a la siguiente:

```js
let filter = {
  $and: [
    {'emisor.profesor': {$exists: true}},
    {'receptor.estudiante': {$exists: true}}
  ]
}

let pathsToPopulate = filter.$and.map(obj => {
  return Object.keys(obj)[0];
});

/* pathsToPopulate contiene:
[ 'emisor.profesor', 'receptor.estudiante' ]
*/

Mensaje.find(filter).populate(pathsToPopulate).exec(callback);
```

En este caso, sabiendo que los documentos devueltos contendrán los campos suministrados en el filtro, se realiza el proceso de *poblado* en campos específicos.

3. **Usar un proceso de *poblado* como parte de un middleware del esquema**

Podemos crear un [*middleware de poblado*](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-middleware) directamente en el esquema de mensaje. De esta forma no necesitamos *poblar* manualmente los documentos sino que vendrán poblados automáticamente cuando usemos algún método al que queramos aplicar el proceso. Por ejemplo esta búsqueda, traerá los campos `emisor` y `receptor` automáticamente *poblados* con los datos que solicitamos:

```js
Mensaje.find(filter, callback);
```

Hay 2 variantes de [`hook`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) (gancho). Los *middleware* previos ([*pre*](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre)) y los *middleware* posteriores o subsiguientes ([*post*](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post)).

Tanto si usamos un *middleware* tipo `pre` o uno `post`, debemos establecerlo como método de nuestro esquema antes de crear el modelo.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// Nuestro esquema
const MensajeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  //...
});

//Nuestra función para poblar
const poblarCampos = function() {
  let pathsToPopulate = [
    {path: 'emisor.profesor'},
    {path: 'emisor.estudiante'},
    {path: 'receptor.profesor'},
    {path: 'receptor.estudiante'}
  ];
  this.populate(pathsToPopulate);
};

// Nuestro middleware pre aplicado a find y findOne:
MensajeSchema.pre('find', poblarCampos);
MensajeSchema.pre('findOne', poblarCampos);

//Nuestro modelo
const Mensaje = mongoose.model('Mensaje', MensajeSchema);
```

De esta forma, cada vez que usemos la consulta con `find` o con `findOne`, obtendremos los documentos con los campos ya *poblados*.

En el caso de usar un *middleware* tipo `post`, podemos incluso ser más selectivos, por ejemplo:

```js
// Esquema
// ...

//Nuestra función para poblar
const poblarCampos = async function(mensajes) {
  for (let mensaje of mensajes) {
    let campoEmisor = mensaje.emisor.estudiante ? 'emisor.estudiante' : 'emisor.profesor';
    let campoReceptor = mensaje.receptor.estudiante ? 'receptor.estudiante' : 'receptor.profesor';
    let pathsToPopulate = [campoEmisor, campoReceptor];
    console.log(pathsToPopulate);
    await mensaje.populate(pathsToPopulate).execPopulate();
  }
};

// Nuestro middleware post aplicado a find y findOne:
MensajeSchema.post('find', poblarCampos);
MensajeSchema.post('findOne', poblarCampos);

//...
```

De esta forma cada documento es analizado para saber exactamente los campos que se necesitan poblar, luego se llama al método `populate` del documento y se ejecuta el mismo con el método [`execPopulate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-execPopulate) que devolverá una Promesa. Notemos que hemos usado una función tipo `async` de tal forma que el resultado del *middleware* sólo estará disponible cuando la Promesa sea resuelta o rechazada.

Comment: MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS!!!!!! Me ha quedado clarisimo, voy a aplicarlo ahora mismo. De verdad gracias!

Comment: Buenas, otra pregunta. Si uso la primera opción, ¿Cómo puedo hacer un populate para que me muestre los datos del emisor y receptor?

Comment: @Ana, he actualizado la respuesta agregando el proceso de populación tal como los necesitas. Saludos